# How to make right click on the restore down button on any window

Tags: windows

I would like to build a Utility that enables me to right click a window on the "Restore Down" and always have it downsized into a fixed size and location on the screen.

I found an Open Source utility that enables me to right click the minimize button and have it reduced into the the icon tray and I would like to add my utility to the existing one.

link to the existing utility repos: https://github.com/benbuck/rbtray

I'm looking for a direction where to start on this little project.

Answer (score 0):

Oh that's easy

**Python has in-build modules like win32gui, win32con**, which makes this thing really easy.

**1. To Maximize Window:**

```
import win32con, win32gui
hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_MAXIMIZE)
```

**2. To Minimize Window:**

```
import win32con, win32gui
hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_MINIMIZE)
```

**3. To restore down window (Normal)**

```
import win32gui, win32con
hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_RESTORE)
```

*Cheers, athrv.*